# Deleting array of class objects?

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

It's almost common knowledge that the code below correctly frees the memory of 100 integers.

```
int* ip = new int[100];
delete [] ip;
```

And I think even for user defined classes it works:

```
Node* ip = new Node[100];
delete [] ip;
```

1. In the first case, is the size of memory to be freed (400 bytes), determined at compile time? Basically, what goes on internally?
2. In the second case, will the destructor  of `Node` be called on each of the 100 objects?

Essentially, I have been using this syntax, but never understood what goes on internally and now I am curious.

Comment: Do use `std::vector<>`, though, in normal use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. No. The memory allocator invisibly keeps track of the size. The size cannot be determined at compile time, because then the allocation would not be truly dynamic and the following would not work:

```
size_t n;
std::cin >> n;
a = new int[n];
// do something interesting
delete[] a;
```

1. Yes. To convince yourself of this fact, try

```
struct Foo {
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Goodbye, cruel world.\n"; }
};

// in main
size_t n;
std::cin >> n;
Foo *a = new Foo[n];
delete[] a;
```

Comment: So is the memory allocator a separate process/thread/module in any compiled C++ program?  And who does the job of calling the destructor in case B? Is it the "memory allocator" or does the compiled code has the instructions to call the destructor? Thanks!

Comment: The memory allocator is part of the C++ standard library. `new` and `delete[]` statements are commonly compiled into calls to functions that wrap `malloc` and `free` or an OS-level interface. The destructor is also called by the memory allocator (it's just a function, after all).

Comment: Oh okay. Makes sense now. Its surprising how I have been using the syntax for long, assuming it magically works, without giving a thought to it.

Comment: So if I dynamically de-allocate an array of 'N' class objects, inside the library de-allocator function, the destructor would be called on each object... sounds fine :)

Comment: Yep, that's how it should be and that's how it is, thanks to `new`/`delete[]`. In fact, they were added to the language mainly to support this construct; with old-school `malloc` and `free` you'd have to call the dtors explicitly.

Comment: I'd say that destructors are more likely to be called by compiler-injected code, rather than the memory allocator as part of language support library.

Comment: @larsmans: @Alexey is right, the allocator is only responsible for allocation and deallocation, but `new []` and `delete []` have a greater responsibility: calculate the amount of needed memory for its use, store the number of elements in some hidden position (usually *before* the actual array) and call the construct in place all of the objects in the case of `new []`, and the inverse in the case of `delete []`: call all of the destructors, then call the deallocator to release the memory. Note that allocators might need to add yet more extra information (number of bytes allocated)...

Comment: "The destructor is also called by the memory allocator (it's just a function, after all)." No. Memory allocator allocate and deallocate memory and that's all (that is why we call it "memory allocator"). _Memory allocator_ for arrays is actually two functions: `void* operator new[](size_t size);` and `void operator delete[](void* ptr);` - they are used to allocate (before the constructors) and deallocate (after the destructors) memory for arrays. They are implicitly defined by the implementation (but usually they may be explicitly defined by the user).

Comment: Ok, sorry everybody for oversimplifying. The memory allocator proper indeed does not call ctors/dtors.